# Justify div text using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to justify some text in a div and no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to where I want. All of the resources I've looked at on using flexbox suggest that my code is right, but clearly it isn't. I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ew6ufk8q/1/) of my current code.

```css
.job-description {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="job-description">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut velit massa, condimentum consectetur quam vel, dictum ullamcorper nulla. Maecenas ac sem hendrerit, finibus nibh vitae, aliquet est. Aliquam consequat ultricies turpis sit amet pulvinar. Aenean
    commodo consectetur sapien eu rhoncus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `text-align: justify`?

Comment: `.job-description p { text-align: justify; }` is what you want? [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ew6ufk8q/2/)

Comment: `justify-content` only affects flex items not the line boxes nor the letters within a line box!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `text-align: justify`

**CSS**

```
.job-description {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.job-description p{
    text-align: justify;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ew6ufk8q/3/)**

Comment: I think I had tried this unsuccessfully before. My text was previously not in `p` tags. Works now though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This seems a conceptual confusion.

> The [`justify-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-justify-content) property aligns [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) along the
>   [main axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-axis) of the current line of the flex container.
>
> [image: An illustration of the five justify-content keywords and their effects on a flex container with three colored items.]

However, you don't want to justify your flex item. Instead, you want to justify the text inside it. So the right way to justify it is using [Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/) properties, not [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1) ones. Specifically, there is [`text-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#text-align):

> This property describes how the inline-level content of a block is
>   aligned along the inline axis if the content does not completely fill
>   the line box.

So you add `text-align: justify` to your flex item. Or if you prefer, to the flex container, and let the flex item inherit it.